# Deserialize to struct with an enum member

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, serde

I am trying to take some json that looks like this:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "name": "some name"
}
```

and use `serde` to deserialize it to a data structure like this:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Quux {
    foo: Foo,
    name: String,

}

pub enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz,
}
```

I [have some code](https://github.com/pwoolcoc/test-deser-struct-w-enum), but to be honest, it is pretty much straight out of the `serde` guide to "deserializing without macros," and I'm not sure exactly what I would need to do to get it to deserialize the `foo` field to a `Foo`.

I have implemented `Deserialize` for the `Foo` enum, which I thought would be enough for the `visitor.visit_value()` call in my `impl serde::de::Vistor for QuuxVisitor` to call that version of `deserialize`, but does not seem to be the case.

The error I get when I try to deserialize to `Quux` is `called 'Result::unwrap()' on an 'Err' value: SyntaxError("expected value", 2, 20)`, but if I change `Quux` to use a `String` for `foo` instead of a `Foo`, it deserializes fine.

Answer (score 3):

There is a full example for Rust 1.18 / serde 1.0.0:

```
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for EventKind {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> result::Result<EventKind, D::Error>
        where D: Deserializer<'de>
    {
        struct FieldVisitor {
            min: usize,
        };

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for FieldVisitor {
            type Value = EventKind;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                write!(formatter, "a string containing at least {} bytes", self.min)
            }

            fn visit_str<E>(self, value: &str) -> result::Result<EventKind, E>
                where E: serde::de::Error
            {
                let kind = match value {
                    "request" => EventKind::Request,
                    "ready" => EventKind::Ready,
                    "next" => EventKind::Next,
                    "reject" => EventKind::Reject,
                    "fail" => EventKind::Fail,
                    "done" => EventKind::Done,
                    "cancel" => EventKind::Cancel,
                    "suspended" => EventKind::Suspended,
                    s => {
                        return Err(serde::de::Error::invalid_value(serde::de::Unexpected::Str(s),
                                                                   &self));
                    }
                };
                Ok(kind)
            }
        }
        deserializer.deserialize_str(FieldVisitor { min: 4 })
    }
}

enum EventKind {
    Request,
    Ready,
    Next,
    Reject,
    Fail,
    Done,
    Cancel,
    Suspended,
}

impl Serialize for EventKind {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> result::Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where S: Serializer
    {
        let kind = match *self {
            EventKind::Request => "request",
            EventKind::Ready => "ready",
            EventKind::Next => "next",
            EventKind::Reject => "reject",
            EventKind::Fail => "fail",
            EventKind::Done => "done",
            EventKind::Cancel => "cancel",
            EventKind::Suspended => "suspended",
        };
        serializer.serialize_str(kind)
    }
}
```

You can see a similar example [here](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.Visitor.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example. I'm not sure about the best way to handle unknown fields, but  this works:

```
extern crate serde;

use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Visitor, Error};

pub enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz,
}

impl Deserialize for Foo {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: &mut D) -> Result<Foo, D::Error>
        where D: Deserializer
    {
        struct FieldVisitor;

        impl Visitor for FieldVisitor {
            type Value = Foo;

            fn visit_str<E>(&mut self, value: &str) -> Result<Foo, E>
                where E: Error
            {
                match value {
                    "bar" => Ok(Foo::Bar),
                    "baz" => Ok(Foo::Baz),
                    _ => Err(E::syntax(&format!("Unexpected field: {}", value))),
                }
            }
        }

        deserializer.visit(FieldVisitor)
    }
}
```

I used Rust 1.6.

Comment: Yes, this will deserialize the enum, but when a struct has a member which has type `enum Foo`, deserializing the struct does not utilize the `Deserialize` impl for `Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [serde_derive](https://crates.io/crates/serde_derive) to generate the `Deserialize` implementations rather than writing them out by hand.

In the code below, I use a `#[serde(rename_all = "lowercase")]` to make `Foo` accept the JSON representations `"bar"` and `"baz"` instead of the default `"Bar"` and `"Baz"` corresponding to their capitalization in the Rust code.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Quux {
    foo: Foo,
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "lowercase")]
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz,
}

fn main() {
    let j = r#"
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "name": "some name"
        }
        "#;

    println!("{:#?}", serde_json::from_str::<Quux>(j).unwrap());
}
```